# Linq filter by several enumerators

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, enumeration

I have enumerator

```
   [Flags]
    public enum ConversionResults
    {
        Added, Validated, ValidationFailed, Uploaded, Processing, Converted, ConversionFailed
    }
```

also list of objects. Objects has Enum property based on ConversionResults.

I am trying to remove all object which has enums "**ConversionResults.Validated, ConversionResults.ValidationFailed, ConversionResults.Uploaded**" but code do not work, the object are not removed.

```
ConversionModelList.RemoveAll(p.Result.HasFlag(ConversionResults.Validated | ConversionResults.ValidationFailed | ConversionResults.Uploaded))
```

Comment: `RemoveAll` isn't LINQ to start with... if you want to use LINQ, you should be using `Where`. But aside from that, are you trying to remove elements with *any* of those flags, or *all* of them?

Comment: I would like to remove all objects which has any of enum value.

Comment: Right, that's not what `HasFlag` does. Will post an answer when I get back from lunch, if no-one else has...

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you need to change.

First, you need to redefine your enum as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum ConversionResults
{
   Added = 1, 
   Validated = 2, 
   ValidationFailed = 4, 
   Uploaded = 8, 
   Processing = 16, 
   Converted = 32, 
   ConversionFailed = 64
}
```

`[Flags]` attribute by itself does not assign power of two to enum values (which is necessary if enum values should serve as flags); you still need to do that manually. The attribute (AFAIK) only affects the way `.ToString()` method works when used to return string representation of enum values.

Second, in `.RemoveAll()` method, your predicate needs to be formed like this:

```
ConversionModelList.RemoveAll(p =>
    p.Result.HasFlag(ConversionResults.Validated) |
    p.Result.HasFlag(ConversionResults.ValidationFailed) |
    p.Result.HasFlag(ConversionResults.Uploaded));
```

This will remove those items that have any of `Validated`, `ValidationFailed` and `Uploaded` flags on.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the flags to match against together using an OR. To determine whether a given flag matches the combination, AND it with the combination and if the result is the same flag, then it matches.

```
var flagsToMatch = ConversionResults.Validated | 
                   ConversionResults.ValidationFailed |
                   ConversionResults.Uploaded;

list.RemoveAll(p => p.Result == (p.Result & flagsToMatch));
```

The `HasFlag` approach works, but can become lengthy when checking against numerous flags.